# Cannot turn wireless networking off

Tags: wireless, networking, system-settings, adapter

I wish to disable my wireless networking because I have a wired network connection.

I am using ubuntu 12.04. In the menu at settings > network > wireless there is an option to press a switch which toggles on/off. If I press this button, my wireless will toggle off. However, it hasn't actually toggled off. I don't lose the wireless IP address. If I close the menu and open it again, the toggle is set back to "on".

I can disable my wired network just fine. My wireless network, however, will not stay off.

The user account is an Administrator.

Comment: Perhaps your computer has a physical hardware switch that can disable wireless... many models have one.

Comment: You can turn your wifi off using sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

Comment: Do you want to turn it off more or less permanently?

Comment: Could you please run **tail -f /var/log/syslog**, then try again switch off wireless in gui network manager. Then print here logs, may be we can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rfkill to achieve that.

Do

```
rfkill list all
```

to get the list of devices attached to your system. Note down the index for your wireless device and then do

```
rfkill block <index>
```

When you want to switch it on again, you can use

```
rfkill unblock <index>
```

If you are concerned that the index might change, you can use just specify it as 'wlan' instead of specifying it by index. Like,

```
 rfkill block wlan
 rfkill unblock wlan
```

Comment: Is this a permanent solution? I don't want to have to shut it off every time the computer boots.

Comment: @melchoir55: If you need the blocking to be permanent, you can add

rfkill block <index> 

to your /etc/rc.local

Comment: I tried adding "rfkill unblock 1" to the end of my rc.local file. The wireless device was index 1 per rfkill list all. When I rebooted I found that my wireless was still on. Further, it had changed from index 1 to index 0. The device on index 1 is now bluetooth. It is also still on.

Comment: Sorry, fixed my file. The blocking does work, and after rebooting my wireless was index 1 again. I'm a little worried that the index might change and the wireless will no longer be disabled. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I have edited my answer to address your query.